# Connecting to Postgresql in a docker container from outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, remote-connection

I have Postgresql on a server in a docker container. How can I connect to it from the outside, that is, from my local computer? What setting should I apply to allow that?

Comment: what command did you use to start the postresql? you're able to expose a port and map it

Comment: Refer this https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/06/02/running-postgresql-database-in-docker-and-connecting-from-host-outside-container/

Answer (score 688):

You can run Postgres this way (map a port):

```bash
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

So now you have mapped the port 5432 of your container to port 5432 of your server. `-p <host_port>:<container_port>`  .So now your postgres is accessible from your `public-server-ip:5432`

To test:
Run the postgres database (command above)

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
05b3a3471f6f        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   1 seconds ago       Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp    some-postgres
```

Go inside your container and create a database:

```
docker exec -it 05b3a3471f6f bash
root@05b3a3471f6f:/# psql -U postgres
postgres-# CREATE DATABASE mytest;
postgres-# \q
```

Go to your localhost (where you have some tool or the psql client).

```
psql -h public-ip-server -p 5432 -U postgres
```

(password mysecretpassword)

```
postgres=# \l

                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 mytest    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres
```

So you're accessing the database (which is running in docker on a server) from your localhost.

In [this post](https://medium.com/@lvthillo/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7) it's expained in detail.

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie You're sure your postgres is running on your local machine? Maybe try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but for met it's working.

Comment: Get your public IP address (osx): `ifconfig -u | grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2 | head -1`

Comment: Of all of the various postgres/docker related posts I have found this is one of the most useful. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to postgres over docker without mapping a local port? For example with something like: `psql -h some-internal-docker-host -p 5432 -U postgres`?

Comment: @GarouDan if you don't want to map a port but still want to access the postgres container from your host you'll need to deploy your container on the host network like this: `docker run --net=host --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres`

Comment: `docker exec -it 05b3a3471f6f bash`

@lvthillo at that line, don't need to write the SHA here, you can replace it as "some-postgres" because the container is named from the command above

Comment: exiting psql works with \q (just for the newbies like me)

Comment: If you have a mac you can replace by  ```psql -h docker.for.mac.localhost -p 5432 -U postgres```. Both of those options works

Comment: But this is access from localhost, by the point view of container. Using other words, you are inside the container and acessing the database, Ok it it useful, but how to connect from outside container?

Comment: @filosofisto you'll need to use your public ip address, I've used the one related to my Wireless LAN adapter retrieved via ipconfig and it's working :)

Answer (score 207):

I managed to get it run on linux

1. run the docker postgres - make sure the port is published, I use alpine because it's lightweight.

   ```sh
   docker run --rm -P -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="1234" --name pg postgres:alpine
   ```
2. using another terminal, access the database from the host using the postgres uri

   ```sh
   psql postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/postgres
   ```

for mac users, replace psql with pgcli

Comment: glad that someone answered how to connect without jumping into the container. thnx.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `sudo` to run your container.

Answer (score 113):

You can also access through docker exec command by:

```
$ docker exec -it postgres-container bash

# su postgres

$ psql
```

Or

```
$ docker exec -it postgres-container psql -U postgres
```

Comment: psql -U postgres

Comment: What does `su postgres` do?

Comment: @Breno `su postgres` means: switch user to the postgres user.

Comment: WORKS amazing. First you need to get the container ID of your docker postgress, use the command "docker  ps -a", then use the continerID with this command: docker exec -it container_ID psql -U postgres

Comment: `psql` after `su postgres` helped

Answer (score 76):

I am using django with postgres in Docker containers. in the docker-compose file, add the following:

```
db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=app
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
    ports:
        - "6543:5432"
```

This `ports` setting uses the port `6543` (it just needs to be different from `5432`) that is accessible by your local machine. For myself, I connected DBeaver to it. this will prevent port clashes between your app request and local machine request.

At first, I got a message saying that the port 5432 is in use (which is by django app) so I couldn't access by pgAdmin or DBeaver.

Comment: I found this to be the most helpful. For people uisng docker-compose, this seems like the best way to go.

Comment: I can confirm this, also this seemingly strange setting of using a port number for the host that is different from the standard while the standard `5432` can be used further for the container at no harm. I had a Windows PostgreSQL installation which was occupying the port `5432` needed to reacht the Docker host, see [Connect to dockerized postgres from Windows Docker host?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929090/11154841).

Comment: And then which IP do you use to connect?

Comment: This worked for me. Port 5432 didn't work. Unsure why as the port is apparently not occupied or excluded on my computer, but alas, switching it to a random port I picked ended up being my solution.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that the docker image can be built and run when mapping to a host port that has been connected to; this effectively means host can NOT connect to the postgres image

Comment: This one worked for me just fine. I've created  postgres on docker using docker-compose. I've been trying different configurations to connect to it but this one worked.

Answer (score 28):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to view data present in your container **everytime** you connect to it from outside. To do this, you will have to **persist** data on the postgres image.

If you don't have persistent data, you will have to repeat everything you did the first time.
***Steps 3, 5, 6, 7, and 8*** answer your question directly.

Here is the detailed overview of the entire process I followed on Windows 10 powershell (commands are the same in Linux and macOS as well):

***Step 1***: Start powershell in non-admin mode

***Step 2***: Download postgres docker image:

```
docker pull postgres:latest
```

***Step 3***: Start docker container in detached mode and persist data on postgres image by creating a volume and binding it to a destination
(**Note**: by default 5432 is the default port that is used; but state it explicitly to prevent connection errors from clients like `pgadmin`, `dbeaver`, etc.)

```
docker run --name postgres-test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
    -p 5432:5432 -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -d postgres:latest
```

***Step 4***: Check status of running containers

```
docker ps -a
```

***Step 5***: Go inside `container_name` in interactive mode
(**Note**: commands like `ls`, `pwd`, etc. can be executed here if you've checked Linux containers during installation)

```
docker exec -it postgres-test psql -U postgres
```

***Step 6***: Create sample data. At this point, you can play with `psql` commands in the following manner:

```
# CREATE DATABASE test;
# \c test
# CREATE TABLE test_table(something int);
# INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (123);
# SELECT * FROM test_table;
# \q
```

***Step 7***: Open a database client application like `pgadmin` or `dbeaver` and enter the below in the connection fields:

```
Host: localhost
Database: test
User: postgres
Password: password
```

***Step 8***: Enter the query

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
```

in the query editor and you should be able to see the output `123`.

Comment: I've followed this exactly, but when I enter the details in dbeaver it says the test database doesn't exist

Answer (score 26):

I know this is late, if you used docker-compose like @Martin

These are the snippets that helped me connect to psql inside the container

`docker-compose run db bash`

`root@de96f9358b70:/# psql -h db -U root -d postgres_db`

I cannot comment because I don't have 50 reputation. So hope this helps.

Comment: Op wants to connect from outside.

Comment: @avizzzy this is just an alternative to what  Ashutosh Gupta said https://stackoverflow.com/a/54865728/10422291

Should've commented there too. Not like I care but should be consistent in life right?

Comment: @RishabhAnand well from now you will be :)

Answer (score 22):

I already had running postgres on host machine and didn't want to allow connections from network, so I did run temporary postgres instance in container and created database in just two lines:

```bash
# Run PostgreSQL
docker run --name postgres-container -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -it -p 5433:5432 postgres

# Create database
docker exec -it postgres-container createdb -U postgres my-db
```

Comment: if you want to create a single default database you can also add:  `-e POSTGRES_DB=my-db` to create my-db instead of postgres

Answer (score 21):

For some reason 5432 port seems protected. I changed my port config from `5432:5432`to `5416:5432` and the following command worked to **connect to your postgres database from outside its docker container**:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5416 -U <my-user> -d <my-database>
```

Comment: It´s works for me but I did not find an explanation on Internet. Did you find?

Comment: @negas You are probably already running the `postgres` service on your host machine which will already bind to localhost:5432 preventing you from using it. Mapping a different host port to the default port 5432 inside the container is a good solution to that; alternatively you could stop the postgres service on your host but perhaps it's used for something you need.

Comment: worked with me after removing the port

Answer (score 20):

Connect to a local container running `postgres`

1. Install `psql`

   ```
   brew search postgres
   brew install postgresql
   ```
2. Start the Docker

   ```
   docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=users \
     -e POSTGRES_USER=john \
     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
     -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
   ```
3. Connect to database

   ```
   psql --host=localhost --username=john --dbname=users
   ```

Comment: that psql command does not work on windows. getting authentication failed error

Answer (score 17):

To connect from the localhost you need to add '--net host':

```
docker run --name some-postgres --net host -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

You can access the server directly without using exec from your localhost, by using:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Answer (score 9):

I tried to connect from localhost (mac) to a postgres container. I changed the port in the docker-compose file from 5432 to 3306 and started the container. No idea why I did it :|

Then I tried to connect to postgres via PSequel and adminer and the connection could not be established.

After switching back to port 5432 all works fine.

```
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "db_sql:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
```

This was my experience I wanted to share. Perhaps someone can make use of it.

Comment: Volume path: `/var/lib/mysql` ?

Comment: 5432 is Postgres default port. 3306 is MySQL default port. If you change the published port in docker-compose then any client tools you try to use to connect will also default to trying to connect to port 5432 unless you tell them to use another port.

Answer (score 5):

first open the docker image  for the postgres

```
docker exec -it <container_name>
```

then u will get the root --`root@868594e88b53:/#`
it need the database connection

```
psql postgresql://<username>:<databasepassword>@postgres:5432/<database>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h localhost -p 3307 -U postgres -d postgres
```

Use the above to load an initial script as:

```
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h localhost -p 3307 -U postgres -d postgres < src/sql/local/blabla.sql
```

Do not that i remap my ports as:

```
docker run -p3307:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, it is a django backend application, you can do something like this.

```
docker exec -it container_id python manage.py dbshell
```

Answer (score 1):

After building my gateway-microservice application i had the same issue. Can not to connect to contenerized postgresql from Heidisql.

At this moment i have solved it by simply specifying postgresql password to docker-compose.yml as well as port.

So you should find and open docker-compose.yml. Then you should enter POSTGRES_PASSWORD (don`t let it to be empty), and specify the port “5432:5432”

services:
microservice33-postgresql:
environment:
- POSTGRES_USER=microservice33
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=wwww
- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
ports:
- 5432:5432

link for reference and screenshots [post](https://yuriyni.com/docker/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside/)

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this thread helped me figure out how to this in Docker Desktop. Figure I would share that info. There are optional settings you can access when creating a new container and you can set the host port here.

[image]

When you go to your containers you should see value in the ports, that's how you know you can connect to the container from your local computer.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`docker ps -a` to get container ids then
docker exec -it  psql -U  -W

Answer (score -2):

There are good answers here but If you like to have some interface for postgres database management, you can install pgAdmin on your local computer and connect to the remote machine using its IP and the postgres exposed port (by default 5432).