# connect to mysql which is running in docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I ran my mysql in a docker container after making a docker network.

`docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16 network-name`

`docker run -p 3306:3306 --net network-name --ip 172.19.0.13 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d`

Then when I tried to connect to mysql in my local with command
`mysql -uroot -p`, I got error  (`Error 2002 (HY000): Can't Connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`)

Then I succeeded with command `mysql -u root -p -h 172.19.0.13`

I thought I connected my localhost port 3306 with docker container's 3306 port.
Why can't I connect to mysql through localhost port?

Comment: What happens if you run without the `--net` flag?

Comment: can you please post output of `docker ps` and `docker port <mysql_container_id>`?

Comment: It's because you created the private network!

Comment: do you really need to run in in a private docker network? otherwise, remove the --net from your command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect to mysql by using a tcp socket or a unix socket .
When you are remote you always use tcp socket .
When you are local mysql client prefer socket .

In your case your need to know where mysql is the unix socket .
you can use :

```
 netstat -npl
```

When mysql run in a docker container , you must be inside the container to have the ability to connect on localhost .

if you are local:

- **mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1** will force usage of a tcp socket
- **mysql -u root -p -h localhost** will use a  unix socket