# DBeaver / PostgresSQL fails to connect to remote docker container

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, docker, jdbc

I'm trying to access a postgresql docker container through DBeaver, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Running `docker port db_1` returns:

```
5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5432
```

So the port should be open to connections.

The `postgresql.conf` is set to

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Running `docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' db_1` returns

```
172.19.0.2
```

When trying to connect to the database to either `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` / `172.19.0.2` / `db_1` the Dbeaver log returns this:

```
2019-03-18 17:22:03.000 - Connect with 'jdbc:postgresql://db_1:5432/test' (postgres-jdbc-169919c23d5-77ac021a71307fee)
....
2019-03-18 17:22:14.815 - SSH INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
2019-03-18 17:22:14.824 - SSH INFO: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
2019-03-18 17:22:14.825 - SSH INFO: Next authentication method: password
2019-03-18 17:22:18.432 - SSH INFO: Authentication succeeded (password).
2019-03-18 17:22:18.458 - Connection failed (postgres-jdbc-169919c23d5-77ac021a71307fee)
2019-03-18 17:22:18.459 - SSH INFO: Disconnecting from domain.com port 22
2019-03-18 17:22:18.461 - SSH INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
2019-03-18 17:22:18.514 - org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: The connection attempt failed.
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:179)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.PostgreDataSource.openConnection(PostgreDataSource.java:363)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.PostgreDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(PostgreDataSource.java:122)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:100)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:89)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.PostgreDataSource.<init>(PostgreDataSource.java:80)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.PostgreDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(PostgreDataSourceProvider.java:97)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:770)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.dialogs.connection.ConnectionWizard$ConnectionTester.run(ConnectionWizard.java:232)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:148)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:157)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Really clueless on how to make the connection work. The SSH tunnel obviously works, but the connection to the db fails. I have a spring boot application running in another container, and connecting that through the connection string `jdbc:postgresql://db_1:5432/test` works like a charm.

Any input on this? Could it be that `0.0.0.0` doesn't get mapped to the internal network somehow?

Comment: `db_1` will only work from another container. 127.0.0.1 should work. Do you have a rule on pg_hba.conf blocking the connection?

Answer (score 2):

How are you exactly running your container, I suspect maybe you are missing to expose the ports? because I just tried running a postgres instance using the following command in PS:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5433:5432 postgres
```

Mapping the default postgres container port 5432 to my local 5433 port (because I have a postgres installation locally and didn't want to run into some kind of port-interferance problem) and later on created a database by accessing the docker and running some psql commands as described on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside) and then accesed the DB from DBeaver

[image]

and everything worked fine! Hope this helps.