# using psql to connect to postgres instance on Hasura created in Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: graphql, digital-ocean, hasura

I have a Hasure GraphQL engine installed through a droplet installation on Digital Ocean.

Even though I gained root access to the droplet instance using ssh I can't connect to the instance inside Hasura droplet docker image.

What are the list of commands to run to connect to postgres instance inside docker image??

Answer (score 2):

Once you `ssh`ed into your Digital Ocean instance, list all running docker containers:

```sh
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
....................................................
```

Take note of the `CONTAINER ID` of the container in question.
Then you can have a terminal session inside of the container, and use `psql` to connect to the database:

```
docker exec -it 05b3a3471f6f bash
root@a5sd22v5-# psql -U postgres
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside) is more relevant.