# How to connect to postgres inside docker based webapplication from pgadmin anywhere outside the docker image?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I have the following container:
`admin@PC:/$docker ps -a`    
returns

| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9c0adfffff | hg/sample:1.1 | "/usr/sbin/init" | 8 days ago | Up 7 days | 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp | agitated_euclid |

This container is a springboot webapp, that maps the application on 80:80. So, the problem is how to access the postgresql that is used by this application inside the same docker container to be accessible from:

1. the host linux machine containing the docker with this container? and,
2. any computer with pgadmin interface to connect to this docker postgresql?

Currently I'm using `sudo docker exec -it 9c0adfffff  bash` command to connect to the docker terminal and accessing database using `psql`, but that doesn't satisfy my current requirement. ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523349/8118238))

I also tried `docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704532/8118238), but I think this fires up the new container, and also that is not what I need. I need to access database of existing container, whose webapp is running on port 80 currently.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the container running a Spring application on port 80, or a PostgreSQL server?  You'd almost always run these in two separate containers.  Either way, if you publish the port of the database container `docker run -p 5432:5432` then you can connect to that published port with `psql` from the host without doing anything Docker-specific.

Comment: its running spring application on port 80.