# How to connect to postgres on another server where postgres is on docker?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, ssh

I can connect to postgres in that way.
On my local machine i run:

1. **ssh name@ip -p 22**
2. input --> **password**

and then

3. **sudo docker-compose exec postgres bash**

after that i have full access to my postgres db.
how can i connect to that DB with python?

I know library like psycopg2, but i didn't found any example how to connect to db which is on another server and with docker ot run.

Comment: Have you take a look at [Connecting to Postgresql in a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside) ?

Comment: If you start the container with a `docker run -p` option as suggested in the linked question, it will appear in all ways like a normal PostgreSQL server running on the remote machine; you can't tell from off-box whether it's in a container or not, and you can interact with it using normal tools, the remote server's DNS name, and the published port.  You shouldn't usually need the `docker exec` debugging tool to talk with a database or other server.

Comment: @KrerkkiatChusap II am new in this and also don't understand how to get this done. When. What does this command in few words? `docker-compose exec postgres bash`, and how to connect to postgres on another server with theese commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three layers here.

1. Your local machine.
2. The server.
3. The container running the database.

Between each layer, there is a gap. Between
(1) and (2) you have the Internet. Between
(2) and (3) you have docker networking.

Now, what you described in the question is this.

You first cross the (1)-(2) gap with SSH then
you cross the (2)-(3) with the command
`sudo docker-compose exec postgres bash`.

Now for your question in the comment, according to
[docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/), `docker-compose exec <container-name or id> <command>` will
run a `command` in a `container`, and `sudo` elevate your privilege to root account.
Since the command is `bash`, you essentially open an interactive shell of the
container.

Now this method of crossing the two gaps will work, and you observed, but for
`psycopg2` library, it will not.

Again with docker documentation, you can tell docker to eliminate the (2)-(3) gap
for you, this is mainly known as [publishing a port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports). You can tell docker to map
a port on the server to a port on the container, so the (2)-(3) gap can be eliminated.
At this point, the connection to a port on the server will be passed to the container
at the defined port.

Now the only gap you need to cross is just (1)-(2) which can now be done by `psycopg2`
easily (given that the firewall is allowing inbound connection on that said port).

Now, the detail on how to tell docker to eliminate the (2)-(3) gap is in the answer to [Connecting to Postgresql in a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37694987/10163723). It also show you how you can connect to the database with `psql` directly from your local machine.