# Postgres db created in docker not shown in psql

Tags: postgresql, docker

Better question and answer that solved my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705699/cant-access-postgres-instance-inside-docker).

I entered a docker container (running a Postgres image) via bash and created a new database called **test**:

[image]

then I connected to it via command line:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432  -U postgres
```

I inserted the password and got in, but when I look at the databases:

```
postgres=# \l
```

I only get 3 databases:

[image]

I'm using Windows 10, Docker version 20.10.16, psql (PostgreSQL) 14.4.

**EDIT**

Command for starting the container:

```
 docker run --name postgres-0 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest
```

Inside docker (**test** db present):

[image]

Outside docker connection (no **test** db):

[image]

Comment: have you tried this? `docker exec -itu postgres yourcontainer psql`

Comment: You are connecting to different Postgres instances, look at the output. One is English the other in Italian and the encodings/locales are different. Best bet is that in the second case you are connecting to database outside the Docker container.

Comment: Why is `psql` generating PNG files; I'd normally expect it to produce plain-text output?  How are you starting the container?

Comment: It sounds like you’ve received an answer on your newer question about this? [Can't access Postgres instance inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705699/cant-access-postgres-instance-inside-docker) If so, it probably makes sense to close this original question.

Comment: I want to but when I click on "delete" a thing pops up saying: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely connecting to two different instances. To access the instance inside the container you can use `docker exec`, e.g.

```
$ docker exec -u postgres postgres-0 psql -c "\l"
```

.. or add `-it` if you intend to keep working with `psql` in the same session

```
$ docker exec -itu postgres postgres-0 psql
```

**EDIT** (see comments): assuming `postgres-0` is the container's name.

```
$ docker exec -u postgres postgres-0 psql -c "CREATE DATABASE test;"

$ docker exec -itu postgres postgres-0 psql -d test
```

Comment: isn't ```docker exec -it postgres-0 bash``` and then ```psql -U postgres``` and then creating my dbs the same things?

Comment: I've done exatcly as this guy suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside

Comment: @IDK not necessarily. You can create and access the db without `bash`. See my last edit.