# How to connect Prisma ORM running inside a container to a PostgreSQL database inside another container using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

### Description

I built a simple RestAPI using **node.js** and **Prisma** as an ORM and created a `Dockerfile` for that application, then i used `docker-compose` to make these services:-

- `web` -> this is the application service, built using the `Dockerfile` mentioned above.
- `pgdb` -> a postgresql container built using the PostgreSQL official docker image.

### The Problem

when i try to run `docker-compose up` it **fails to build** the `web` service because **Prisma can't run it's migrations due to it's inability to connect to the database that's running in the other service, namely `pgdb`.**

### The Specific Error Message

> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `pgdb:5432`.
> Please make sure your database server is running at `pgdb:5432`.

*note: i used `pgdb` (the name of the PostgreSQL service) here to reference the host.*

### Expected Behavior

it should be able to use `pgdb` as a host reference and successfully connects to the database server located at `pgdb:5432`

### Code

- The `Dockerfile` referenced inside the `docker-compose` to create the `web` service

  ```
  FROM node:16

  WORKDIR /app

  COPY package*.json .

  RUN npm install

  COPY . .

  # Run Prisma migrations.
  RUN npx prisma migrate dev --name init

  # Compile typescript code to javascript.
  RUN npx tsc

  # Run the compiled code (compiled files are outputed to `dist` folder).
  CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
  ```
- The `docker-compose.yml`

  ```
  version: "3.9"
  services:
    webapp:
      build: .
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
      depends_on:
        - pgdb
    pgdb:
      image: postgres:14
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
  ```
- The `.env` (containing Prisma DB connection string)

  ```
  DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@pgdb:5432/mydb?schema=public"
  ```

### Versions

- Node `v16.17.0`
- Prisma `^4.4.0`

Comment: it doesn't make sense to run migrations at docker image build time.  The migrations should be run within the entrypoint of the image, not when its being built.  Otherwise how would you ever run them in production / dev environments?

Comment: omg, I made modifications based on your advice and everything worked, I just did what you said, modified the Dockerfile to run migrations within the image entrypoint, thank you so much i have been trying for 2 days!!, please post an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> # Run Prisma migrations.
> RUN npx prisma migrate dev --name init
> ```

it doesn't make sense to run migrations at docker image build time. The migrations should be run within the entrypoint of the image, not when its being built.

Then when the container is deployed, the migrations run before the application is started in each environment in which it's deployed.

Comment: Can you describe where this line is supposed to go, please? Where is the “entrypoint of the image”?

Comment: The most ergonomic approach is to specify a dockerfile  1ENTRYPOINT` of a  shell srcipt that applies migrations before `exec`ing the application.  `exec` is important so bash replaces itself as the container process.

Comment: Thanks @erik258. Unfortunately this is too abstract for my understanding. Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Prisma is experiencing difficulty connecting to your PostgreSQL database. I encountered a similar issue documented on Stack Overflow, which indicated that Docker might be facing challenges connecting to your locally hosted database. Another potential issue could be related to PostgreSQL configuration settings, specifically, whether you have enabled connections from all hosts in your PostgreSQL configuration.
Link: [Connecting to Postgresql in a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside)