# Connect to the Postgresql in a docker container that runs in the linux of vmware from local computer

Tags: postgresql

I have VMware and navicat on my windows and CentOS works in the VMware.I installed docker on CentOS, and wonder how to use navicat to connect the PostgreSQL that runs on a docker container.

[img0-connect to postgresql successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N57Jy.png)

[img1-student table in database template1 of posgresql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cAvs.png)

[img2-no talbes show in navicat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnILN.png)

I have searched for relevant information online, but I still cannot solve this problem."
Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks!

```
1. set " listen_addresses = '*' " in postgresql.conf
2. open the port 5432 on centos
3. docker run -p 5432:5432 \
    -v /var/lib/pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data\
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx\
    -e LANG=C.UTF-8\
    --restart=always\
    --name postg11\
    -d postgres:11-alpine
```

Comment: Your last screenshot shows that you are connected to the "postgres" database, not "template1" database. They are different.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Firstly I thought that "postgres" showed in the last screenshot may be the username, because when I try to connect to different database, such as "template1" , it still shows "postgres".Here is the url [image3](https://i.postimg.cc/pL0qyVFn/image.png). I have try to use the "template1" database in the navicat,but failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to Postgresql in a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694987/connecting-to-postgresql-in-a-docker-container-from-outside)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two databases in your cluster; template1 and postgres.The database `postgres` is normally there when you spin up your PostgreSQL server and is selected by default when you connect without specifying specific database or when you run `psql` in your terminal provided you have created `postgres` user and the current terminal user is `postgres`.
In your CentOS terminal,run:
`psql -d template1`
The command above outputs the psql terminal for template1 database.
Then,you can run : `SET DEFAULT_DATABASE = template1;` to make template1 your default database.